# Using loops to search for names from file1 in file2 and writing to file3

Tags: python, for-loop, search

I'm new to Python and kind of pulling my hair out here. I've tried for several things for a few hours and no luck.

I think it's fairly simple, hopefully. I'm trying to search for names from file1 in file2 by stripping the newline character after being read. Then matching. If found I'm trying to write the whole line from file2 to file3. If nothing found then write just the name to file3.

**File1:**

```
Abigail
Alexa
Jamie
```

**File2:**

```
Abigail,infoA,infoB,InfoC
John,infoA,infoB,InfoC
Jamie,infoA,infoB,InfoC
```

**File3:**

```
Abigail,infoA,infoB,InfoC
Alexa
Jamie,infoA,infoB,InfoC
```

**Test Data file1:**

abigail
anderson
jan
jane
jancith
larry
bob
bobbie
shirley
sharon

**Test Data file2:**

abigail,infoA,infoB,infoC
anderson,infoA,infoB,infoC
jan,infoA,infoB,infoC
jancith,infoA,infoB,infoC
larry,infoA,infoB,infoC
bob,infoA,infoB,infoC
bobbie,infoA,infoB,infoC
sharon,infoA,infoB,infoC

This version worked but only read and wrote the first instance.

```
import re

f1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
f3 = open("file3.txt", "w")

for nameinfo in f1:
    nameinfo = nameinfo.rstrip()

    for listinfo in f2:
        if re.search(nameinfo, listinfo):
            f3.write(listinfo)
        else
            file3.write(nameinfo)
```

This version worked but it wrote the name (that had no match) over and over while looping between matches.

```
import re

f1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r")
f3 = open("file3.txt", "w")

list2 = file2.readlines()

for nameinfo in file1:
    nameinfo = gameInfo.rstrip()

    for listinfo in list2:
        if re.search(nameinfo, listinfo):
            file3.write(listinfo)
        else
            file3.write(nameinfo)
```

Is it possible to use simple basic loop commands to achieve the desired results? Help with learning would be greatly appreciated. I see many examples that look incredibly complex or kind of hard to follow. I'm just starting out so simple basic methods would be best in learning the basics.

Comment: Will you have always the same number of lines in file 1 and 2? or it can differ?

Comment: They do have a different number of lines. File2 may even have duplicate entries that will be matched. I'll need to remove them eventually but I'm just trying to take it one step at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your second solution keeps writing the unfound name is because it searches each line of `file2.txt` looking for a match and adds to `file3.txt` each time.

What you can do instead is introduce a new variable to store the value you want to add to `file3.txt` and then outside of the loop is when you actually append that value to your file.

Here is a working example:

```py
import re

# note the .read().split('\n') this creates a list with each line as an item in the list
f1 = open("file1.txt", "r").read().split('\n')
f2 = open("file2.txt", "r").read().split('\n')
f3 = open("file3.txt", "w")

for name in f1:
    # Edit: don't add aditional new line
    if name == '':
        continue

    f3_text = name

    for line in f2:
        # if we find a match overwrite the name value in f3_text
        # EDIT 2: don't match on partial names
        # These are called fstrings if you haven't seen them before
        # EDIT 3: using a regex allows us to use the ^ character which means start of line 
        # That way ron doesn't match with Sharon
        if re.search(rf"^{name},", line):
            f3_text = line

    # at this point f3_text is just the name if we never 
    # found a match or the entire line if a match was found
    f3.write(f3_text + '\n')
```

Edit:

The reason for the additional new line is if you look at `f1` you will see it is actually 4 lines

```py
f1 = ['Abigail', 'Alexa', 'Jamie', '']
```

Meaning the outside for loop is ran 4 times and on the last iteration `f3_text = ''` which causes an additional new line is appended. I added a check to the for loop to account for this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of my issue. Your example makes sense and worked but I noticed it adds two blank lines at the end of the file vs. one. Is it possible to get rid of the second newline? Also, why does it add it at the very end only vs. adding it for each loop?

Comment: @Arnie that is because the `f1` file has a new line at the end which is read in as part of the list. I edited the answer with more details and a fix

Comment: -Hi, after testing I noticed the script isn't working correctly. It seems to duplicate names that have similar bases. Such as Jan, Jane and Jancith so it might write Janicth twice but not Jan. I don't quite see the pattern. On the other hand I used Jakub Szlaur script it seems to add entries that don't exist but doesn't duplicate. By that I mean it will add entries from file2 that don't exist it file1. I checked both files and all lines end in CR/LF and all the names are comma delimited. They are very consistent. They are also small around 250k (file1) and 750k (file2).

Comment: I added "test data 1" and "test data 2" data to the OP. If you use that data with your script you'll see what's happening. It will print Jancith twice (ignores Jan) and Bobbie twice (ignores Bob). Also I noticed it doesn't seem to write them out in the same order that it reads them. The 1st line in file3 is some random name that is not the top of file1 or file2. Also of note is file2 may have duplicate entries that may get written to file3 but in the example their are no duplicates but it will illustrate what's happening. I am using Python 3.8.3 and NotePad++ on Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Good catch, the reason it was duplicating names is in python, `"Jamie" in "Jamielynn" = True` so if we are searching "Jan" it will match on whatever if finds first be it Janicth, Jane, etc.

There are a few ways around this, but the easiest would be to check for "name," that way the comma signifies the next entry and we've matched the entire name. I've edited my answer with this correction

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’ll test it out and let you know. I haven’t heard of them but I will look it up to see if it makes more sense. I’m trying to learn something new during COVID (a bit of Python) but I’ll probably not attain the level like you pro’s so thank goodness for sites like this. I hope you have a great evening and thank you.

Comment: I apologize as it's taken a little longer than expected. I have a test file that has around 6500 names (file1) from about 20,000 entries (file2) and it still doesn't seem to be working quite right. I do have some niche cases that have numbers in front or behind the name. I've spent several hours trying to reproduce it in a smaller case. The names are still all comma delimited before the next field. If I understand you're matching everything up to the comma right? That seems like it should cover all scenarios but something still isn't quite right and I'm not seeing it as of yet.

Comment: If you upload the full text files to something like pastebin.com and then edit your original question with those links and the specific lines with errors I can take a look

Comment: I though about that but then thought uploading 20,000 identities probably wouldn't be the wisest idea. Not that I think you would do anything nefarious at all to be sure. :) I did find the issue I think. It's very similar. If you have "sharon" and "ron" in file1 both of those match the data line for sharon and completely ignore the ron data line. So in file3 I have sharon data twice and no ron data. Ron is way before sharon in the list (top to bottom) but it goes all the way down toward the bottom and still chooses sharon for both.

Comment: I hope this helps and isn't asking to much. I started printing the variables and I think I see what's happening. It finds a match for ron but continues down the list and finds sharon which overwrites the ron data in f3_text and that's what gets written to the file. Then sharon is searched and it only matches sharon so it writes her data a second time. I'm ok with finding the first exact match if I have to pull more "unique" data into the first field but is there a way to stop these partial matches so it has to match the two words exactly from end to end?

Comment: Ah gotcha, no worries I didn't realize this was real data.  The problem is Python's `in` just checks for any part of the string in the search string.   In order to match the entire name and not sub parts, we will have to use a regex. I've edited my answer with a new `if` condition that covers this

Comment: You're a rockstar! That did it! I apologize if anything came across as dodgy as it was never meant to. It's real data but just changing it up a bit. I did some programming 30+ years ago with COBOL, Fortran, RPG, BASIC and even a bit of C so a lot of the concepts I can catch on or at least follow but the syntax in Python can get very cryptic quickly with search patterns and such. The project I'm working won't mean much to anyone but I feel a sense of self growth learning something new and I enjoy it more importantly. I appreciate your help and learned several new things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it in pure Python without using the regex module (if you don't wanna learn it's minilanguage):

```
with open("file1.txt", "r") as f:
    names = f.readlines()

with open("file2.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

names = [name.strip() for name in names] #strip of all other unwanted characters

with open("file3.txt", "w") as f:
    for name in names:
        to_write = name + '\n'

        for line in lines:
            if name in line: #If we find a match rewrite 'to_write' variable adn Break the for loop
                to_write = line
                break

        f.write(to_write)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. This makes sense and is pretty clever too. I appreciate how you guys can break it down and make it more simple to use and understand.